# Visual Studio Team Services Compile LESS scripts during build

Tags: asp.net, azure, less, azure-devops

I'm deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to an Azure Website using VSTS's Continuous Integration.  Everything works great except compiling LESS files.

I looked through the build steps and I couldn't find anything specific to LESS.  Is there any documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy actually.  You just have to set it's build action property to "content" and everything should be good to go.

If that doesn't do the trick, I found this blog post detailing another method to try (note that I haven't tried this technique myself yet):
In Visual Studio, open the properties of your web project, go to the "Build Events" section, and the in the section "Post-build event command line", insert the following line:

```
$(SolutionDir)\packages\dotless.1.1.0\Tools\dotless.Compiler.exe -m "$(ProjectDir)\content\*.less" "$(ProjectDir)\content\*.css"
```

Every time the project builds, this command will compile any .less file in the \content folder into a corresponding .css file, minifying it as well (with the -m switch).

Here is the post that contained this information:
http://tech-journals.com/jonow/2011/05/13/using-less-css-with-asp-net